# How would i use /fill to fill an area with downward-facing dispensers filled with a bucket of lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command for my server to fill an area of 516 blocks with downward-facing dispensers each carrying 1 bucket of lava. This is for a prison system. version 1.16.4 Vanilla

Comment: dunno the command but you would just need to add some nbt tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command for this is:

```
/fill <x1> <y1> <z2> <x2> <y2> <z2> dispenser[facing=down]{Items:[{id:"lava_bucket",Count:1b,Slot:<slot>}]}
```

Where  `<x1> <y1> <z2> <x2> <y2> <z2>` refers to the coordinates of the place you want to fill and `<slot>` specifies where in the dispenser the bucket of lava is stored (`0` = top left, `8` = bottom right)

Comment: I'm not in a position to dictate your style of writing commands, but I will encourage you, please specify your NBT data types! This will cause less confusion later down the road when people try to test for these numbers.

Comment: Also your NBT data holds a trailing comma, I think. Please remove it.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of using `/fill`, I don’t think you can do that unless you want to fill the area with lava. I personally made something like this in my world before. First, I actually placed dispensers facing downwards that way I wanted to (so in your case, place 516 downward dispensers), then fill each of them with a lava bucket. I then just used the `/clone x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3` command in a **command block** to copy the structure or you can alternatively save and load it using **structure blocks and redstone**. To prevent mistakes when cloning, try it out somewhere else first so you know where you should clone the structure.

Comment: "I don’t think you can do that unless you want to fill the area with lava" im not sure what all the nbt tags for a dispenser is, but im pretty sure slots and direction are in it